# Obsolete syntax warning in dlmread

Tags: matlab

I'm completely new to Matlab, so I've been tying out the various IO functions to see how they operate.  Here I try to construct a matrix from a tab-delimited spreadsheet:

```
%Matrix test
M = dlmread('MyFile.txt', '\t', 1);
disp(M);
```

The output:

```
>> MatrixTest
Warning: Obsolete syntax. C must be specified with R. 
> In dlmread (line 91)
  In MatrixTest (line 2) 
    0.3800    0.2900    0.0400    0.2900  -22.2000
    0.4600    0.4500    0.0200    0.0700  -22.2500
    0.4900    0.1500    0.0200    0.3400  -66.7700
    0.1000    0.8100    0.0200    0.0700  -81.7500
    0.1200    0.5700    0.0500    0.2600  -49.5000
    0.3000    0.6000    0.0300    0.0700  -57.4700
    0.4200    0.0900    0.0100    0.4800  -56.3500
    0.2600    0.2800    0.2900    0.1700  -79.7900
    0.4800    0.0300    0.4000    0.0900  -76.8500
    0.2600    0.0100    0.1400    0.5900  -28.6600
    0.2900    0.5000    0.1900    0.0200  -21.5700
    0.1400    0.8300    0.0200    0.0100  -31.2700
    0.0200    0.4700    0.1300    0.3800  -93.1500
    0.0400    0.5000    0.3500    0.1100  -16.9500
    0.1100    0.0100    0.1300    0.7500  -11.0500
    0.2000    0.6700    0.1200    0.0100  -44.7900
    0.3900    0.3600    0.1700    0.0800  -18.7300
    0.1500    0.3300    0.0600    0.4600  -48.4500
    0.3900    0.0800    0.2300    0.3000  -60.6100
    0.3400    0.3600    0.2200    0.0800  -33.0800
    0.1400    0.7800    0.0200    0.0600  -60.5000
    0.3600    0.6300    0.0100         0  -46.6700
    0.1600    0.4800    0.0700    0.2900  -38.2800
```

The code works as expected, but apparently I've used obsolete syntax (or maybe the issue is with the dlmread function?).  Anyway, what is the more appropriate way to perform this same operation?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What makes you think this is obsolete? If it's an editor prompt, it usually corresponds to a note in the docs (there isn't one) and there is usually an alternative suggested. There are many ways to read ascii files, depending what you want to do...

Comment: I think it is obsolete because of the warning issued in the output.  It's the second line above:
" Warning: Obsolete syntax. C must be specified with R."
I don't know what 'C must be specified with R' means, but it doesn't seem to be suggesting an alternative.

Comment: Per [the documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dlmread.html) (and the warning), a column input needs to be specified in addition to a row input.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this

```
%Matrix test  
M = dlmread('MyFile.txt', '\t', 1, 0);  
disp(M);
```

Here, for ignoring first column - use:

```
%Matrix test  
M = dlmread('MyFile.txt', '\t', 1, 1);  
disp(M);
```

Thanks